# Black soot on spark plugs

Tags: sparkplugs

I just took my spark plugs out on a 2006 V6 Toyota Tacoma and noticed some soot on most of them, to varying degree. Could this indicate that the engine is burning oil? I do lose quite a bit of oil and am not sure if I am burning or leaking. Here are two of them, one with more:

[image]

and one with less soot:

[image]

Comment: I am surprised they are not platinum ; your engine would still have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wet black deposits are indications of oil consumption, burning excess oil from worn piston rings and/or valve stems. Blue smoke from exhaust is a tell tale  sign of oil burning along with wet black plugs. Dry black coated plugs would indicate excessive rich fuel mixtures.  Normal plugs are dry with a tan color on the center ceramic and brown deposits from  residue of light amounts of oil consumption during combustion. There are spark plug charts with images describing how they wear and what deposits originates to coat them.